# xsd fixed into C# const

Tags: c#, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd.exe

I need to define a field in an xsd file, that, when converted in C# classes using the XSD Tool, will turn into a const field (or something similar), for the purpose of not allowing any other values to be stored in the field.

At the moment, I have

```
<xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" use="required" fixed="01.01.01"/>
```

which is converted to a simple field with its associated property, and the parent's constructor will contain a definition to the respective value :

```
private string versionField;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute("mantec_assembly_order")]
public string refSchema 
{
     get 
     {
         return this.refSchemaField;
     }
     set 
     {
         this.refSchemaField = value;
     }
}
```

and the constructor

```
public Foo() 
{
    this.versionField = "01.01.01";
}
```

Is it possible to obtain a C# field with a fixed value, equal to the value inside the `fixed` attribute in the XSD file, by converting this file into a C# file using the XSD tool?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: What does `const` have to do with this? What are you asking exactly?

Comment: For the sake of interpretation, I would always rephrase what I need into a simple question.

Comment: Edited to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no.

As to make it a const (to allow, for e.g., to use it as a case label in a switch statement), for sure it is not going to work.

The reason has to do with the inner working of the XML serializer.

Comment: Thanks, I will start searching other possibilities to achieve what I need.